# Get Track Image in Spotipy

Tags: python, spotipy

I am trying to get the currently playing track's cover to put on a separate window. I am using Spotipy, and I cannot seem to find how to get the track's image. Is there any way to get the cover using Spotipy?

Answer (score -1):

I've never used spotipy, but I checked out the docs quickly and the second example on the [Getting Started](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?highlight=image#welcome-to-spotipy) page shows how to get the URL for an album image. The next example shows how to get the image for a given artist. I'll show the one that references album art:

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

lz_uri = 'spotify:artist:36QJpDe2go2KgaRleHCDTp'

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())
results = spotify.artist_top_tracks(lz_uri)

for track in results['tracks'][:10]:
    print('track    : ' + track['name'])
    print('audio    : ' + track['preview_url'])
    print('cover art: ' + track['album']['images'][0]['url'])
    print()
```